# Check for changed properties in WPF MVVM Binding

Tags: mvvm, data-binding, inotifypropertychanged

I'm binding properties from an object like this:

**ViewModel**:

```
public class VieModel
{
    public Model MyModel 
    { 
        get
        {
            return myModel;
        } 
        set
        {
            myModel = value;
        }
    }
    private Model myModel
}
```

**Model**:

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Info { get; set;}
    public string MoreInfo { get; set;}
}
```

**View**:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.Name, Mode=TwoWay, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus }" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.Info, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus }" />
<TextBox Text="{Binding MyModel.MoreInfo, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=LostFocus }" />
```

Everything is working fine but when `MyModel` changes, I would like to check if any property has changed so I can ask the user to save first.

So my first thought was to add a boolean which turns to true on any change so I can check for that in the setter of `MyModel`. But currently I don't get a notification on `MyModel` when I change a Property even though it does in the background..

All in all i get it, cause `MyModel` does not really change.. but how do i detect any a change on any property?

Thanks in advance! :)

---

## Answer:

To check if the current `MyModel` is the same as the old one u need to store copy of that object to be able to compare them as described by Bijington [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50018094/check-for-changed-properties-in-wpf-mvvm-binding/50019106#50019106)

For that you can do it manually or use a Binary-Serializer so you can clone your mobject.

**manually:**

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Info { get; set;}
    public string MoreInfo { get; set;}

    public static Model Clone(Model obj)
    {
        Model newModel = new Model();

        newModel.Name = obj.Name; 
        newModel.Info = obj.Info; 
        newModel.MoreInfo = obj.MoreInfo; 

        return newModel;
    }
}
```

**BinaryFormatter.Serialize**:

You need **EVERY** object used in you `Model` to have the `[Serializable]` attribute.

```
[Serializable]
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set;}
    public string Info { get; set;}
    public string MoreInfo { get; set;}
    public SecondModel SecondOne { get; set;}

    public static Model Clone(Model obj)
    {
        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            var formatter = new BinaryFormatter();
            formatter.Serialize(ms, obj);
            ms.Position = 0;
            return (T)formatter.Deserialize(ms);
        }
    }
}

[Serializable]
public class SecondModel 
{
    public string SecondName { get; set;}
    public string SecondInfo { get; set;}
    public string SecondMoreInfo { get; set;}
}
```

Comment: When exactly do you need to know if there are any changes to `MyModel`? If it is at the point of changing the value of `MyModel` you could handle it inside the property setter and provide an implementation of `IComparer` to check if anything has changed

Comment: You must implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface. As shown here https://stackoverflow.com/a/49955379/3587031

Comment: @k1ll3r8e - As i said, the binding is working well. ;)

Comment: @Bijington - thats what I need. Never workes with a IComparer. Will have a look at it. Or could u give an easy example for this? Would be great! :)

Comment: @bene_rawr I have added a basic example although not using IComparer now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have slightly changed my approach from the initial comment. Instead of implementing `IComparer` the option I have gone with is to override the `Equals` method.

```
public class Model
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Info { get; set; }
    public string MoreInfo { get; set; }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is Model model)
        {
            return string.Equals(this.Name, model.Name, StringComparison.Ordinal);
            // && Add your other property comparisons here...;
        }

        return false;
    }

    public override int GetHashCode()
    {
        // You really should provide your implementation here:
        return base.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

Then once you have set up the Model class like the above you can do the checks inside your ViewModel class:

```
public class VieModel
{
    private Model myModel;

    public Model MyModel
    {
        get
        {
            return myModel;
        }
        set
        {
            if (myModel?.Equals(value) != true)
            {
                // The model has changed so you can perform what you want here...


                myModel = value;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Okay, that kinda worked. Thanks! Had to do a few other things do accomplish my scenario but now it is working like a charm.